# Getting integers from a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am trying to extract the integers from a string.

String :

```
Str = "(Start = 10) AND (End_ = 40)"
```

Note: The integers here can range from 1 - 999, single digit to three digits

Desired Output:

```
No1 = 10
No2 = 40
```

Comment: Please show your attempt(s). What isn't working in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Here is my attempt:

var clause = "(Start = 231) AND (End_ = 24)";
                      var s_node,e_node, cnt=0;
    for(i=0; i< clause.length; i++){
     var a = parseInt(clause[i]); 
     if(Number.isInteger(a))
     {
      if(cnt == 0){
      s_node = a;
      cnt++
      }
         else{
      e_node = a;
      }
      
     }
     
    }
console.log(s_node, e_node)

This works if I have single digit integer within a string.
Works if, var clause = "(Start = 1) AND (End_ = 4)"
fails if, var clause = "(Start = 231) AND (End_ = 24)"

Comment: `00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2}`

Comment: Note that 1-3 digits are not enough to describe the problem,  since `204`55 will also match. You'd need to add a boundary condition or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will get you what you want, an array of numbers found in the string.

#### Explanation

The regular expression looks for a single number 1 through 9 `[1-9]` followed by 0, 1, or 2 `{0,2}` numbers between 0 through 9 `[0-9]`. The `g` means global, which instructs `match()` to check the entire string and not stop at the first match.

#### Code

```js
var str = "(Start = 10) AND (End_ = 40)";
var numbers = str.match(/[1-9][0-9]{0,2}/g);

console.log(numbers);
```

Comment: Updated the regular expression to NOT capture 0, or any number prefixed by 0.

Comment: There wont be "0" in the main string however, I can make the changes accordingly.

Comment: `single digit to three digits` so can it start with `0` like 001 ?

Comment: @sln, No it will not have 0.
eg: 1,2,3,.......,11,12,.......,111,...,999

Comment: Cool, then the updated regex will work perfectly for you.

Comment: @AnonymousSB , No it will not start with 0. however can contain 0 in between and at end
eg: 1,2,3,.......,10,11,12,.......,101,...,990
Sorry for confusion

Comment: Yes, my solution allows that. The second or third number can include 0